# jquery undisable list onselect

Tags: jquery

I have a list of options dependent on what is selected in the first option. How can I make it so that after they select location the second options only displays options avaliable to that location?

Right now I have a bunch of

```
<option class=2 DISABLED>Blah</option>
```

jQuery Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#location').change(function() {
    $(.$(this).val()).removeAttr('disabled');
  });
});
```

The value of the location option is = to the class of the second. But it doesn't seem to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sanitys sake I would change around that selector to something along the lines of:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#location').change(function() {
    var curLoc = $(this).val();
    $('.' + curLoc).removeAttr('disabled');
  });
});
```

Edit- Per Jon Cram `<option disabled>` is acceptable in non-xhtml doctypes.

Comment: <option disabled="disabled"> is valid only if using an XHTML doctype. <option disabled> is perfectly valid for HTML.

Answer (score 2):

The selector needs to be in quotes.

```
$('.' + $(this).val()).removeAttr('disabled');
```

Comment: And if you also specifies the context there will be much better performance (selecting by only classname in the whole DOM isn't that fast):
$("." + $(this).val(), $("#theSelect")).removeAttr("disabled");